# Powershell - Scripting login

Tags: html, powershell, scripting

I'm attempting to automate a time card report from a network time clock that for some reason, has email alerts but can't email time cards (smh).

Here's what I'm looking at:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="formMain">
<div><label for="username">Username/PIN</label> <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" />    </div>
<div><label for="password">Password</label> <input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="" onKeyPress="capsLockOn(event);" />    </div>
<div><label for="ClockTime">&nbsp;</label><div id="ClockTime">Not Available</div></div>
<div class="buttons"><label for="submit">&nbsp;</label> <input class="colorSettings" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="document.getElementById('buttonClicked').value='Submit';" /></div>
<input id="buttonClicked" type="hidden" name="buttonClicked" value="none"/>
</form>
```

And using the following code, I'm at least able to prefill the username and password fields:

```
$Url = “http://URL”
$Username=”user”
$Password=”pass”
$IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$IE.visible = $true;
$IE.navigate($url);
while ($IE.Busy -eq $true)
{Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000;}
$IE.Document.getElementById(“username”).value = $Username
$IE.Document.getElementByID(“password”).value=$Password
$IE.Document.getElementById(“buttonClicked”).Click()
```

But I can't get it to click the Submit button.

Any constructive advice would be greatly appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to click the button, you could use this as your last line and submit the form.

```
$IE.Document.getElementById("formMain").submit()
```